# Php foreach loop wrapped every 2items with a row

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="puffar">
    <?php
    //Set up the objects needed
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

    //Get children
    $children = ($post->post_parent) ? get_page_children($post->post_parent, $all_wp_pages) : get_page_children($post->ID, $all_wp_pages);

    $i = 0;
    //Build custom items
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="puff">
                <div class="puff-image-holder">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($child->ID, 'full'); ?>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                    <legend><?php echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></legend>
                </fieldset>
                <?php echo get_field("puff_introtext", $child->ID); ?>
                <?php
                $values = get_field('puff_lanktext', $child->ID);
                if (get_field("popup_eller_lank", $child->ID) == "popup") {
                    ?>
                    <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                        <legend><a class="linktopage open-popup"
                                   href="<?php echo get_page_link($child->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_field("puff_lanktext", $child->ID); ?> </a>
                        </legend>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php
                } elseif (get_field("popup_eller_lank", $child->ID) == "extern") {
                ?>
                <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                    <legend><a class="linktopage"
                               href="<?php echo get_field("puff_lank", $child->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_field("puff_lanktext", $child->ID); ?> </a>
                    </legend>
                    <?php
                    $i++;
                    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                        echo "</div><div class='row'>";
                    }
                    } else {
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I want every 2 items that's rendered out to be wrapped in a `<div class="row">`, however I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

So basically the row should wrap every 2 elements that is getting looped. I have been stuck on this forever... Hopefully anyone got better expertise than me hehe.

The `div="row"` should wrap the `col-sm-6` and `class="puff"`.

Comment: I formatted it for you sir. You already messing with code and you still have unformatted code in your Editor. Its horrible. Please use modern IDE which does  auto Reformatting.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com thankyou. could you edit it so the loop works with the row? ;/

Comment: check the updates in answer.

Answer (score 1):

use proper logic

```
    if ($i % 2 == 0) { 
        echo "</div><div class='row'>";
    }
    $i++;
```

First check if its mod by 2 or not (Gives 0 value after MOD), then close div , open new.

Now increase counter . Because for the first time , i will be 0 , then you increment it and then you use logic. So in short counter shoul be incremented at the end only not in between before you do any operation/logic.

**Updated**

Use code as it is **: issue was you have i++ and your condition in 3rd else if which never executed. So took it outside All and just before foreach.

```
<div class="puffar">
    <?php
    //Set up the objects needed
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

    //Get children
    $children = ($post->post_parent) ? get_page_children($post->post_parent, $all_wp_pages) : get_page_children($post->ID, $all_wp_pages);

    $i = 0;
    //Build custom items
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="puff">
                <div class="puff-image-holder">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($child->ID, 'full'); ?>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                    <legend><?php echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></legend>
                </fieldset>
                <?php echo get_field("puff_introtext", $child->ID); ?>
                <?php
                $values = get_field('puff_lanktext', $child->ID);
                if (get_field("popup_eller_lank", $child->ID) == "popup") {
                    ?>
                    <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                        <legend><a class="linktopage open-popup"
                                   href="<?php echo get_page_link($child->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_field("puff_lanktext", $child->ID); ?> </a>
                        </legend>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php
                } elseif (get_field("popup_eller_lank", $child->ID) == "extern") {
                ?>
                <fieldset class="linedHeadline hlmedium">
                    <legend><a class="linktopage"
                               href="<?php echo get_field("puff_lank", $child->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_field("puff_lanktext", $child->ID); ?> </a>
                    </legend>
                    <?php

                } else {
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo "</div><div class='row'>";
        }

        $i++;
    } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working :( still not wrapping the looped elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $i++;

    // your code goes here 
    if($i % 2 == 0) { 
        echo "</div><div class='row'>";
        // reset the counter to 0 
        $i = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary to reset the counter as `4%2` or `6%2` equal 0 too !

Answer (score 0):

First set $i=0;

```
if ($i % 2 == 0) { 
        echo "</div><div class='row'>";
    }
    $i++;
```